# Calculating $ \tan w$ for $ w = \dfrac{1} {i} \log\dfrac{1-iz} {1+iz}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

Let $ w = \dfrac{1} {i} \log\left(\dfrac{1-iz} {1+iz}\right)$ and calculate $\tan w$.

I begin by using the fact that

$$ \tan w =  \frac{\sin w}{\cos w} =  \frac1i\frac{e^{iw} - e^{-iw}}{e^{iw}+e^{-iw}}$$

I now replace $  w = \dfrac{1} {i} \log(\dfrac{1-iz} {1+iz})$ and get

$$\tan w = \frac{1} {i} \left(\frac{{e^{\log(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz})} - e^{-{\log(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz})}}}} {e^{\log(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz})} + e^{-\log(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz})}}\right). $$

It is at this point that i run into troubles. The next step should be to use the fact that

$$e^{-{\log(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz})}} = e^{{\log(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz})^{-1}}} = e^{{\log(\frac{1+iz} {1-iz})}}.  $$
The thing that i have a hard time grasping is why
$$e^{-{\log(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz})}} = e^{{\log(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz})^{-1}}} $$ is true for complex numbers aswell, since i've always worked under the assumption that the normal logarithmical rules doesn't always apply when it comes to complex numbers. How come it applies here?

Comment: Have you thought of the question of whether the standard rule that $e^{\log x}$ is true of complex numbers $x$ in general?

Comment: Maybe a separate question on whether $-\log a= \log\dfrac1a$ is true of all $a\in\mathbb C$ should be posted. It has the complication that $\log$ is multiple-valued. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy im not quite sure i understand the question. It is all pretty new to me but the way i was thinking is that all the rules apply for complex numbers aswell if we don't limit $e^{\log z}$ to a specific branch. Is this correct or am i far off?

Comment: For purposes of this question, it probably makes sense to construe $\log\dfrac{1-iz} {1+iz}$ to mean some complex number $a$ for which $e^a = \dfrac{1-iz} {1+iz}.$ And then one probably would want to show that for all such complex numbers, the value of $\tan\dfrac a i$ is the same. I think that will probably emerge from applying some more algebra.

Comment: @MichaelHardy you are right, often we feel so confident with numbers that we forget that complex ones are nasty :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of asking whether then rule that $-\log a= \log\dfrac1a$ is true of all $a\in\mathbb C,$ it seems simpler to use the rule that $e^{-b}= \dfrac 1 {e^b}$ for $b\in \mathbb C.$ That tells you that
$$
e^{-\log a} = \frac 1 {e^{\log a}} = \frac 1 a.
$$

Then:
\begin{align}
\tan w & = \frac 1 i \left(\frac{e^{\log(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz})} - e^{-{\log(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz})}}} {e^{\log(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz})} + e^{-\log(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz})}}\right) \\[12pt]
& = {} \frac 1 i\cdot \frac{\frac{1-iz}{1+iz} - \frac{1+iz}{1-iz}}{\frac{1-iz}{1+iz} + \frac{1+iz}{1-iz}} = \frac 1 i \cdot \frac{(1-iz)^2 - (1+iz)^2}{(1-iz)^2 + (1+iz)^2}
\end{align}
and so on.

Comment: Does this mean that the rule that $ -\log a= \log\dfrac1a$ holds true for all $a\in\mathbb C,$, except a = 0 of course?

Comment: @Fosofof : You can view it like this:
$$
\begin{align}
\log a & = \log(re^{i(\theta+2\pi n)}) \\ {} \\
& = (\log r) + i(\theta+2\pi n). \\ {} \\
\log \frac1 a & = \log\left( \frac 1 r e^{ - i(\theta+2\pi m)} \right) \\ {} \\
& = -(\log r) - i(\theta+2\pi m).
\end{align}
$$
But there is the question of the extent to which $\log a$ is well defined when $a\in\mathbb C\smallsetminus\mathbb R. \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

Use

$$e^{\log (a)} = a,$$

and

$$e^{-\log(a)} = \frac{1}{a}.$$

Then:
$$\tan w = \frac{1} {i} \left(\frac{{e^{\log\left(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz}\right)} - e^{-{\log\left(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz}\right)}}}} {e^{\log\left(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz}\right)} + e^{-\log\left(\frac{1-iz} {1+iz}\right)}}\right) = \\
= \frac{1}{i} \frac{\frac{1-iz}{1+iz} - \frac{1+iz}{1-iz}}{\frac{1-iz}{1+iz} + \frac{1+iz}{1-iz}} = \\
= \frac{1}{i} \frac{\frac{(1-iz)^2 - (1+iz)^2}{(1+iz)(1-iz)}}{\frac{(1-iz)^2 + (1+iz)^2}{(1+iz)(1-iz)}} = \\
= \frac{1}{i} \frac{(1-iz)^2 - (1+iz)^2}{(1-iz)^2 + (1+iz)^2} = \\
= \frac{1}{i} \frac{1-z^2-2iz - 1 + z^2 - 2iz}{1-z^2-2iz + 1 -z^2 + 2iz} = \\
= -\frac{1}{i} \frac{4iz}{2(1-z^2)} = \\
= \frac{2z}{z^2-1}.$$

Comment: It seems to me that it the poster asks whether the rule that $-\log a= \log\dfrac 1 a$ applies to $a\in\mathbb C,$ they could still wonder how you justify that when you say $e^{-\log a} = \dfrac 1 a,$ since it might seem as if you thought $$ e^{-\log a} = e^{\log \frac 1 a} = \frac 1 a $$ and there you use the rule that was called into doubt. But if instead you say
$$
e^{-\log a} = \frac 1 {e^{\log a}} = \frac 1 a
$$
then the rules being used are $e^{-b} = \dfrac 1 {e^b}$ and $e^{\log a} = a,$  which are different rules, and which would then justify the identity that was in doubt.

Answer (score 1):

We can try in a separate way:

$$e^{iw}=\dfrac{1-iz}{1+iz}$$

Use https://qcweb.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm,

$$iz=\dfrac{1-e^{iw}}{1+e^{iw}}=-i\tan\dfrac w2$$

Now use $\tan2x$ formula